# Does ServiceBusReceiver use a pull or a push communication model when talking to Azure Service Bus?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics

Just out of curiosity: What exactly happens behind the scenes when we call and await `ServiceBusReceiver.ReceiveMessageAsync()` or `ServiceBusReceiver.ReceiveMessageAsync(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10))`?

Does

a.) the `ServiceBusReceiver` (long-)poll Azure Service Bus or does

b.) Azure Service Bus send somehow push notifications to the `ServiceBusReceiver`?

I tried to look into the [source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/src/Receiver/ServiceBusReceiver.cs#L330-L333), but didn't get far, because some class `InnerReceiver` is used that I couldn't find in the code base.

Comment: Ran to the same problem... waiting to see if anyone has an answer for this.
Maybe you can test it using network screener and look at the network communication with azure...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**FINAL EDIT**

On the ServiceBus Sdk level it is a pull communication model, just to better handle confirmation of incoming messages.

But behind the scenes azure service bus sdk uses Advanced Message Queuing Protocol 1.0 which doesn't long poll, it uses `AmqpLink`s on the same `AmqpConnection` to send data from a sender to a receiver, and the receiver saves the incoming messages to an in-memory buffer on receiving them.

You can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-amqp-protocol-guide#connections-and-sessions)
or See this video series from Microsoft about the [AMQP 1.0 protocol](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLmE4bZU0qx-wAP02i0I7PJWvDWoCytEjD).

So it seems that the answer to "What exactly happens behind the scenes" is neither A nor B, Messages are being pushed to the `ReceivingAmqpLink` (to an in-memory buffer), which then the `ServiceBusReceiver` pulls from.

I hope this answer will close this discussion, and everyone will be happy :)

The source codes:

[Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/main/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus)

[Azure.Amqp](https://github.com/Azure/azure-amqp)

[`ServiceBusReceiver` wraps the `AmqpReceiver`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/src/Receiver/ServiceBusReceiver.cs#L189)

[wrapping the `ReceiveMessagesAsync` of the `AmqpReceiver`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/src/Receiver/ServiceBusReceiver.cs#L330)

[Creating the `ReceivingAmqpLink` in the constructor of the `AmqpReceiver`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/src/Amqp/AmqpReceiver.cs#L196)

[Opening the `ReceivingAmqpLink` on the same connection if possible](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/src/Amqp/AmqpReceiver.cs#L227)

[Caching the messages on the `ReceivingAmqpLink`'s buffer](https://github.com/Azure/azure-amqp/blob/master/src/ReceivingAmqpLink.cs#L739)

[Pulling the messages from the buffer into the `ReceiveAsyncResult`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-amqp/blob/master/src/ReceivingAmqpLink.cs#L811)

[The public async function that creates the `ReceiveAsyncResult`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-amqp/blob/master/src/ReceivingAmqpLink.cs#L145)

[Calling the that "public async function" on `AmqpReceiver.ReceiveMessagesAsync`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/src/Amqp/AmqpReceiver.cs#L367)

Comment: Actually, I am not sure about this. Just now, I've come across [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/technology-choices/messaging#pull-model) by accident: `A consumer of a Service Bus queue constantly polls Service Bus to check if new messages are available. The client SDKs and Azure Functions trigger for Service Bus abstract that model. When a new message is available, the consumer's callback is invoked and the message is sent to the consumer.` So I guess, it's polling after all.

Comment: Ok so after your comment I did some more reading and it's not completely true.
The `AmqpReceiver` implementation doesn't use polling in it's root. It accumulate the messages sent through the AMQP connection to a inner in memory queue, end expose a thread safe very high level in-memory polling system for the user to use. The `ServiceBusReceiver` is just a wrapper class for the `AmqpReceiver` and expose the "polling system" to use.

Comment: So you're saying messages are pushed to the client and then locally polled from memory? That would be nice.

Comment: It looks like it :)

Comment: Maybe your answer could be even better if you provided a deep-link to the source code pin-pointing where and how exactly `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus` is referencing/calling `Azure.Amqp`. The provided links only point to the repository roots. Not criticizing, just optimizing. ;-)

Comment: Just did hope it will be helpful :)

Comment: Ethen's answer is correct; the client API pattern is pull-based for receivers and push-based for the processor.  Under the covers, credits are managed on a persistent AMQP link to control message flow.  When prefetch is not used, credits are only placed on the link when a receiver asks for messages (which is continually for the processor and when ReceiveAsync is called for the receiver)

Comment: Nice source spelunking, by the way.  :)

Answer (score 2):

I think @Ethen.S answer is not correct. Moreover neither (a) nor (b) from original question are true:

- Service Bus in its core is pull based system (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/technology-choices/messaging#pull-model)
- `ServiceBusReceiver.ReceiveMessageAsync` seems to be implemented in "[async all the way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming)" fashion as far as IO for this individual operation is concerned, meaning async operation is initiated, caller thread is "released" and then at some point async operation is completed upon notification and awaited `Tasks` are completed, continuations queued, etc... Note that it does **not** mean that the whole `Service Bus <-> Consumer` interaction can be considered a "push model" because a `Client` of the `ServiceBusReceiver` has to do **polling** on top of it.
- The only mentioned "push model" integration seems to be possible via Event Grid (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-to-event-grid-integration-concept?tabs=event-grid-event-schema)

You might want to take a look at `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusProcessor` (use `StartProcessingAsync` method as an entry point for investigation) source to better understand the dichotomy there. It exposes an `event` that you subscribe to and handle the messages "reactively", but it still does a sequence of the `ReceiveMessageAsync` for you.  What might look "push" model from the consumer perspective might still rely on "poll" model behind the scenes.

Please also note that there is a concept of `Message Prefetching` which can optimise some of the consumption scenarios, but it has its caveats to be considered as well (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-prefetch?tabs=dotnet#why-is-prefetch-not-the-default-option). It is still the same polling strategy, but with an additional client-level buffer on top.

**UPDATE.** I dug deeper into that to capture what happens on wire.

I've used `sslsplit` in order to make MITM attack to capture TLS-protected AMQP connection decrypted data. Test application setup is simple:

- Receiver is doing `ReceiveMessageAsync` in a loop
- After some time sender sends a message (two times)

In summary, this is indeed neither "poll" nor "push" as definitions are rather vague. What we can say for sure is that:

- it uses persistent TCP connection
- receival is controlled by the Client side using "Link Credit" (via the "flow" performative)
- when client is idle waiting for messages once in about 30 seconds empty AMQP message is sent
- Service Bus has mechanism to notify the receiver efficiently if there are enough "Link Credit"

I've put test code and test harness here: https://github.com/gubenkoved/amqp-test.

Below is the capture results, I've colored sender/receiver TCP streams as red/green.

[image: capture]

Comment: This is only the ServiceBus sdk interface and what I called the "Polling System". If you will dig down to the AMQP 1.0 implementation you will see that all messages sent through an AMQP link are being sent from the sender and saved to an in-memory buffer. After the "Polling System" asked for those messages and finish processing them, the receiver (ours `ReceivingAmqpLink`) will send back a confirmation that we successfully processed the messages.

Comment: I fully edited my answer to be more precise, behind the scenes it doesn't long poll the messages from service bus.

Comment: To be pedantic, it's not inherently push or pull, it's a streaming model where message flow is controlled by the client via managing credits on an AMQP link.  How eagerly messages are streamed in depends on whether prefetch is enabled.   Whether or not you consider it "polling" really comes down to how you define the term.

Comment: @JesseSquire I agree with you. The protocol has attributes of both approaches. Thank you for this comment! I will look into expanding my answer later on this one.

Comment: @JesseSquire I've added packet capture results to show what is really happening on wire

Comment: LGTM.  WireShark does a nice job of capturing individual AMQP frames.   For completeness, it may also make sense to link to the discussion of AMQP + Service Bus, which itself links out to the official AMQP spec, in case folks are interested in the low-level details.  https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-amqp-overview

Answer (score 1):

According to [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/technology-choices/messaging#pull-model) of the Azure Application Architecture Guide, Azure Service Bus consumers use a poll model when talking to Azure Service Bus:

> Pull model
>
> A consumer of a Service Bus queue constantly polls Service Bus to check if new messages are available. The client SDKs and Azure Functions trigger for Service Bus abstract that model. When a new message is available, the consumer's callback is invoked and the message is sent to the consumer.

Since `ServiceBusReceiver` is such a consumer, it probably uses polling.

Comment: I would like if you can show me in the source code where exactly the polling occurs.

Comment: I can't. I only quoted the official documentation above which I tend to trust. However, I am still not 100 % percent convinced myself. Hence, I have not accepted either of our two answers, yet. I am still hoping for an answer from some Microsoft person.

Comment: @Ethen.S I have just seen the edits in your answer. That convinces me.

Comment: I am with you on that, Microsoft's documentation is a shit show.

Comment: I wouldn't be that harsh. Overall I find it rather good compared to other documentation. :)

Comment: No idea who owns that doc, but it's incorrect - or at least inaccurate, depending on your definition of "polling".  Regardless of client, a persistent AMQP connection and link are established, allowing messages to stream in.  The client controls this flow by adding credits to the link which controls how much data the service streams down.  For a receiver, messages stream eagerly when prefetch is enable; without prefetch only when ReceiveAsync is called.